# PHP grouping of options in optgroup

Tags: php, html-select, optgroup

I am working on a woocommerce site and I need to find a way to group select options in optgroups.

My option are stored as array like

```
aray = [  
            "A4 1.9tdi (2003-2009)",  
            "A4 2.0tdi (2003-2009)",  
            "Passat B7 1.9tdi(2003-2009)",  
            "Passat B7 2.0 tdi(2003-2010)"  
        ]
```

No what I need is to make by php a select that would group the options in optgroup by using the string up to first space

By using the function

```
explode(' ',$s, 2) or by strpos($inputString, ' ');
```

I can split the values as required.

I need to adapt the code that I am currently using for showing options:

```
$html = '<span class="number">' . ($level + 1).'</span><select class="'.$class.'" name="'.$levelData['url_parameter'].'" '.$extra.'>;
    foreach ( $this->getLevelOptions($level) as $val ){
      $html .= '<option value="'.esc_attr( $val ).'" '.($val == $value ? 'selected' : '').'>'.esc_html( $val ).'</option>';         
    }
    $html .= '</select>';

    return $html;
```

So I can show the options grouped by optgroup like:

```
A4 (optgroup)
A4 1.9tdi (2003-2009)  
A4 2.0tdi (2003-2009) 
Passat (optgroup)
Passat B7 1.9tdi(2003-2009)  
Passat B7 2.0 tdi(2003-2010)
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Your `$html variable does not close with a single quote properly. Likely just a copy paste error.

Comment: You're looking for `<optgroup label="A4">
    <option value="1.9tdi(2003-2009)">1.9tdi(2003-2009)</option>
    <option value="2.0td(2003-2009i(2003-2009)">2.0tdi(2003-2009)</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Passat">
    <option value="1.9tdi(2003-2009)">1.9tdi(2003-2009)</option>
    <option value="2.0tdi(2003-2010)">2.0tdi(2003-2010)</option>
  </optgroup>` This is how you wish to display it yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formats to option group placing the values in the `value` attr within each option. 
`<option value="1.9tdi (2003-2009)">` and wraps it all in a select tag.

```
$cars = array(
    "A4 1.9tdi (2003-2009)",  
    "A4 2.0tdi (2003-2009)",  
    "Passat B7 1.9tdi(2003-2009)",  
    "Passat B7 2.0 tdi(2003-2010)"
);

foreach($cars as $car){
    $model = explode(' ', $car, 2);
    $make[$model[0]][] = $car;  
}

$stmt = 'Select a car: <select id="cars">';
foreach($make as $label => $type){
    $stmt .= '<optgroup label="'.$label.'">';

    foreach($type as $car){
        list($mk, $cr) = explode(' ', $car, 2);
        $stmt .= '<option value="'.$cr.'">'.$cr.'</option>';
    }
    $stmt .= '</optgroup>';
}

$stmt .= '</select>';
```

In html echo out your $stmt variable.

```
<?=$stmt?>
```

https://3v4l.org/bb2nR

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your html part. (It's very hard to read on mobile at least)
But this will probably do what you want, just replace the placeholder html tags.

I first create a new array which is associative on the first word (car model).
This also ensures that it's sorted when I start outputting.

Then I just output the key and implode all values in the subarray.

```
$array = [  
            "A4 1.9tdi (2003-2009)",  
            "A4 2.0tdi (2003-2009)",  
            "Passat B7 1.9tdi(2003-2009)",  
            "Passat B7 2.0 tdi(2003-2010)"  
        ];

foreach($array as $val){
    $temp = explode(" ", $val);
    $new[$temp[0]][] = $val;
}

foreach($new as $car => $cars){
    echo "<some html tag>". $car . "</Some html tag>\n";
    echo "<some other tag>" . implode("</some other tag>\n<some other tag>", $cars) . "</some other tag>\n";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
<some html tag>A4</Some html tag>
<some other tag>A4 1.9tdi (2003-2009)</some other tag>
<some other tag>A4 2.0tdi (2003-2009)</some other tag>

<some html tag>Passat</Some html tag>
<some other tag>Passat B7 1.9tdi(2003-2009)</some other tag>
<some other tag>Passat B7 2.0 tdi(2003-2010)</some other tag>
```

https://3v4l.org/N8YTu